# How to use awk with a for loop?

Tags: linux, awk

I have a 5 column file

```
2       649     2       82      1
3       651     1       83      1
2       652     3       84      2
...     ...     ...     ...     ...
```

The first column is `n` number of points in segment, the second is the `x` coordinate, the third is delta x, the delta between the current `x` coordinate and the next one, similarly the fourth column is the `y` coordinate and fifth is delta y. I need to generate all points in the segments so the output should be, from the data in the first line

```
649     82
650     82.5
```

From the data in the second line

```
651     83
651.33  83.33
651.67  83.67
```

From the data in the third line

```
652     84
653.5   85
```

Any idea How to do it?

Comment: You also need to explain how to arrive at that output from the input. Is it sorted? some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do:

```
    awk '{n=$1; x=$2; dx=$3; y=$4; dy=$5;  \
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) printf "%.2f %.2f\n", x+i*dx/n, y+i*dy/n; }' file
```

You can adjust `%.2f` as you desired. For e.g. `%.4f` to print 4 digits of fraction.

---

I only used variables for clarity. Otherwise, you could simply do:

```
awk '{for(i=0;i<$1;i++) printf "%.2f %.2f\n", $2+i*$3/$1, $4+i*$5/$1; }' file
```

Comment: Last question, I'd like to round the values so instead of printing 83.67 I'd like to print 84, how can I do it?

Comment: @e271p314 You mean ceil if fraction is more than `.5` ? If so, you could do: `awk '{for(i=0;i<$1;i++) printf "%d %d\n", $2+i*$3/$1+0.5, $4+i*$5/$1+0.5; }' file`

Comment: Yes, ceil if more than `.5` and floor otherwise

Comment: No, this was the first thing I tried.
$ awk '{for(i=0;i<$1;i++) printf "%d %d\n", ceil($2+i*$3/$1), ceil($4+i*$5/$1); }' db.txt
And I got
awk: (FILENAME=db.txt FNR=1) fatal: function `ceil' not defined

Comment: @e271p314 `ceil` is not an awk function. You could try this: `awk '{for(i=0;i<$1;i++) printf "%d %d\n", $2+i*$3/$1+0.5, $4+i*$5/$1+0.5; }' file`

Comment: I'm looking for something like `round` I don't want to add .5 regardless of the value. I can always use "printf "%d %d" to floor all values. My question is can I be more accurate

Comment: There's no round or ceil function in `awk`. You could use this [round function[(http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Round-Function.html) if you want. But I can't see why adding `0.5` won't work in all cases. Do you have any example where it'll fail?